# Unity3D: How can i make my player go where i clicked with the mouse, without nav mesh agent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move my player around in my level without a NavMesh Agent.
I was thinking something about raycasting, but i have tried everything and even looked up videos and searched on google about it, can't seem to find anything that works

Plz help!

Comment: do you mean like this? https://answers.unity.com/questions/773911/move-object-to-mouse-click-position.html

Comment: Yeah it worked for me, but the problem now is just that when i click, the player of my game kind of transform to that place, i need him to kind of walk to the place where i clicked, now he is just teleporting to the place where i clicked

Comment: Are there colliders in the environment? Are you using an orthographic or perspective camera? This question is currently too broad to be adequately answered in a single answer. Voting to close until it is made more specific.

Comment: Also, you're surely only interested in [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript] answers

Comment: The code sample from the link I posted does teleport, as it sets the position directly. The second answer talks about interpolation and links off to another tutorial, perhaps that would help?

Answer (score -1):

you can use this for moving to mouseclick position.

This method will move object or player to the position where mouse is clicked on screen.

sorry for syntax error i have typed directly here

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    bool isplayermove = false;
    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start () 
    {
        Vector3 playerpos = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
        {
            is moveplayer = true;
        }

        if(ismoveplayer)
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(input.mousepos.x,input.mousepos.y,input.mousepos.z);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,new Vector3(mousepos.x,transform.position.y,mousepos.z),speed * time.deltatime);
            if(transform.position == mousepos)
            {
                ismoveplayer = false;  
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No not really .. this will move the player for exactly 1 single frame per click... It will also moove the player towards the camera in Z direction

Comment: ok i understant what you were telling hope this edit will work

Comment: Yes now it is better. It still relies on the game being 2D though ;)

Comment: Now its just throws the player directly into the Camera

Comment: This only works for orthographic cameras where the player's transform should always have z=0.